# How do I remove one audio stream from an AVI file?

Tags: video, audio, video-editing

I have several AVI files that have dual audio in Russian/English. The default audio is Russian, and I want to change the default language or remove the Russian language from these AVI files.

How could I achieve this? I don't want to change the audio stream every time I play the movie.

Are there any free tools?

Answer (score 9):

I was able to do this with the [Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) (GUI) program

Main menu: Audio -> Select track; you select the tracks you want to keep, and
save as a new file.

Just in case, Avidemux is in the standard Fedora Linux repository; I'm sure it is standard in Ubuntu/Debian, too.

---

[ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) (console) is also able to do this:

$ ffmpeg -i file.avi -map 0:0 -map 0:3 -acodec copy -vcodec copy  file.1-track.avi

(keeping the video track, and audio track #3), but on one of my files the resul I got with Avidemux was better.

Answer (score 4):

[VirtualDubMod](http://virtualdubmod.sourceforge.net/) also provides the ability to choose which audio streams you want to keep (after selecting the audio stream, you can set the video and audio options to direct-copy, then save it). Of course if the AVI has VBR audio, it may have audio-sync problems because VDubMod has not been updated in a long time and doesn’t support it, and [nandub](http://ndub.sourceforge.net/) which *does* support VBR audio, doesn’t have a way to (easily) select which audio stream you want.

[Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/) has the (limited) ability to use [dual audio tracks](http://avidemux.berlios.de/doc/en/dualaudio.xml.html), so it should also be able to select one from two.

Comment: The OP has confirmed that Avidemux worked for him, btw.

Answer (score 2):

Recoding is a ridiculous solution. Just use a player that you can customize to automatically choose your preferred language. e.g., Use [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org). It's free and considered one of the best.

Go to *Tools > Preferences > Audio* and on this page enter your "Preferred Audio Language."

Comment: that's not what the user asked

Answer (score 1):

I don't see it recommend but I think you can do this with [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/). Just open the AVI up in Handbrake then click on the Audio tag. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Give DVD Flick a try.  I recall seeing an option to set various defaults, and one of them might be the language option.

DVD Flick
  http://www.dvdflick.net/

DVD Flick is free, open source software for making DVDs.  If you're ultimately wanting to produce a .ISO file that can later be burned on to a DVD, then this solution will hopefully be the right one for you.